# S3 Boto Downloading - Most Recent

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I am new to Python coding and havent been able to progress on this. I have some time encoded filenames in the following format:

```
20121208151318.gzip
20121208151320.gzip
20121208151322.gzip
20121208151325.gzip
20121208151326.gzip
```

Using this code I can print the filenames of all the files in my S3 bucket:

```
import boto
s3conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3conn.lookup('my_bucket_name')
for key in bucket:
  print k.name

key.getfile()
```

I need help with two aspects. Firstly how can I get the name of the most recent file in the bucket, which would in my case be:

```
20121208151326 (15:13:26 - 8th December 2012)
```

Secondly, how can I then download this file? I found the key.getfile() command but I cant work how to implement it.

Comment: did you try max(key)? key.get_contents_to_filename(<file_name>)?

Comment: key.get_contents_to_filename(<file_name>)? as a replacement for key.getfile()

Comment: assuming that you need the content of the gzip file, get_content_to_file/get_content_to_filename should be fine.

Comment: Can you add it to an offical answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your format `latest = max(keys)` should get the latest item

To download the content of of the file your can use

```
latest.get_contents_to_filename(<file_name>)
```

or

```
latest.get_contents_to_file(<file>)
```

See more details in [boto documentations for S3](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html)

Comment: Add to get the keys list:

'keys = [key for key in bucket]'

Comment: Thank you. I dont fully understand, I have this code: https://gist.github.com/4246555 . What should I be putting in for "key for key in bucket"?

Comment: This is simply the Python syntax for List Comprehensions: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html